# Is a Declined Invalid Flag Good?

Tags: support, flags

I like to go through my flags and learn from how they went.

I don't understand what happened here:

I reviewed a flag of a question, I reviewed a flag and deemed it an invalid. Even left a message why I thought it was invalid.

Now it shows status declined. It's ambigous to me if my deeming of the flag invalid was declined (and if so why?) or the flag itself was.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: flag]

[This is the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813890/allign-radiobutton-inside-div/16814079#16814079) Assuming that marking the flag as invalid was the right thing to do, could we make what happened here clearer to people who see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's bad. You flag another flag as an "invalid flag" by choosing the "invalid flag" option in the dialog. Any other method casts an *actual flag* on the post in addition to the flag you were looking at. You, as a 10k user, cannot add an explanation to your invalid flag flags. Assuming you typed something out in the "other" box, you created a custom flag on the post, which was declined by a moderator (probably when they dismissed the other flag you were trying to mark as invalid).

[image: Invalid Flag]

When you correctly flag another flag as invalid, it will inevitably get dismissed as "disputed" whenever a moderator gets around to handling it.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the system works this way.

Comment: I find the phrasing here ironic. "it needs diamond moderator attention" --> "...incorrect and should be ignored."

Answer (score 4):

Both of the flags were declined; strictly-speaking, this means your flag was valid (since it implied that the other flag should be declined) - but since moderators don't currently have a good way to dismiss individual flags, both of them got the same status (and response).

So... Good call on identifying a bogus flag; next time use [the special flag reason animuson talks about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183266/is-a-declined-invalid-flag-good/183268#183268).

Comment: Thanks, this further clarifies the issue.